# How can I fix this routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, the signout link isn't working and I'm not sure what I can do to fix it. In my Heroku logs, when I try to signout from my user account, I get the following error:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/signout"):

I have the following route in my config/routes.rb file:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

And in my session controller I have the following method:

```
def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

And then in my session_shelper.rb file I have the following sign_out method:

```
  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
```

Everything seems to be correct from my perspective, so I'm not sure what is causing the error or how I can fix it. My app is hosted on Heroku in case that's helpful. Thanks so much!

sessions_controller.rb

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to info_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end


           <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <% if signed_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
            </ul>
            <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

to

```
match '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy', :via => :delete
```

change

`method: "delete"` to `:method => :delete`

Comment: Okay, let me try this solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1483441 what version of rails are you using?, i edited the answer by the way.

Comment: @user1483441 can you post more details about your code like where are you calling signout_path in the controller controller name etc?..

Comment: Did you state `method: :delete` in your sign out link?

Comment: @user1483441      change method: "delete" to :method => :delete

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help. I just made the change you suggested and pushed that change up to Heroku. Unfortunately, it still isn't working.

Comment: @user1483441 what version of rails are you using? also, you already mentioned the method as 'delete' in the link_to tag. so you need not mention again in the routes saying via => delete

Comment: Okay, after I deleted the code in my routes saying via: delete, it worked. Thank you so much!